# How to check if an element is transparent (opacity) because of some parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Take following example:

```js
const nested = document.querySelector("#nested")
const opacity = getComputedStyle(nested).opacity
console.log(opacity)
```

```css
#parent{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: .2;
}

#nested {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="nested">nested</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see `#nested` is transparent because `#parent` has it's `opacity` set to `.2`, which is expected.

**Question**

How can I check if `#nested` is transparent (= opacity less than 1) because of **some** parent element? `getComputedStyle` unfortunately doesn't work as seen in the example above.

(In my case the parent element that declares the `opacity` value, can't be easily accessed with selectors, because it's not unique. Thus I would appreciate a solution without directly accessing the parent element by an id (or similar), but rather by purely working with the nested element.)

Comment: `getComputedStyle` will always return `1`, as the transparency is on the **parent**. To find out a parent, use `closest()` method.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov `closest()` is actually a good hint! But I am curious if you could find it out, without knowing which parent is declaring the `opacity` value at all (so you don't know that it's `#parent`).

Comment: You need to check all the parents, and find the closest parent whose fears are less than 1. This can be tried through cycle `for`.

Comment: I was afraid to here this and hoped that there would be a better solution.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution allows you to find the **closest** parent whose **opacity** rule is **less than 1**. This means that it is this found parent that will affect the transparency of the **child**.

The search for an element **starts with a child** element, loop `for()`, so this will not cause any load.

```js
let nested = document.querySelector("#nested")

function findOpacityElement(el) {
  for (; el && el !== document; el = el.parentNode) {
    if (getComputedStyle(el).opacity < 1) {
      console.log(el);
      console.log(getComputedStyle(el).opacity);
    } else {}
  }
};

findOpacityElement(nested);
```

```css
#parent{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity: .2;
}

#nested {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="nested">nested</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man! :) you just have a small typo in the second css class: `#parent`should be `#parent2`

Comment: @ysfaran, Oops. I forgot to remove this when I was testing the code. Now I fixed it. Happy to help :)